# Ruby On Rails - Active Model Serializer; Create a custom JSON serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash, active-model-serializers

how can I create a json with this key & value mapping?

- The key should be the attribute 'id' of the record.
- The value should be the attribute 'name' of the record.

i.e.

```
[{ "21": "Jason" },
{ "22": "Britney" },
{ "25": "Donald" },
{ "#{id}": "#{name}" }]
```

Is it possible to achieve this using the [Active Model Serializers gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a serializer?

```
users.map{|u| { "#{id}": name }.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation for the has_many relationship but an example might look like

```
class OrganizationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :users, :key => :id, :serializer => UserSerializer
end

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name
end
```

You could then run that with

```
OrganizationSerializer.new(organization).to_json
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried @B Seven's answer and it works clean and propertly.

Comment: I can see how a serializer model would be useful if you have many attributes or associations. However, I wonder why an ActiveModel Serializer is better than a PORO serializer.

Answer (score -2):

sure it can, please read documentation. May be this [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable) suits your question

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Page not found rendering this answer useless. Should not post links without content in the answer.